# C++ error C 2664 Cannot convert parameter from "IID *" to "const IID&"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My code:

```
IID              xIID_ICMLuaUtil;

if (IIDFromString(T_IID_ICMLuaUtil, &xIID_ICMLuaUtil) != S_OK) {
        break;
}

r = ucmMasqueradedCoGetObjectElevate(
        T_CLSID_CMSTPLUA,
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        &xIID_ICMLuaUtil,
        NULL);
```

ucmMasqueradedCoGetObjectElevate function :

```
HRESULT ucmMasqueradedCoGetObjectElevate(
_In_ LPWSTR clsid,
_In_ DWORD dwClassContext,
_In_ REFIID riid,
_Outptr_ void **ppv);
```

REFIID :

```
#define REFIID const IID * __MIDL_CONST 
IN c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\guiddef.h line 119
```

Error:

Error C2664 "HRESULT ucmMasqueradedCoGetObjectElevate(LPWSTR, DWORD, const IID &, void **)": Cannot convert parameter 3 from "IID *" to "const IID &" test2 c:\users\son\desktop\60\test2\ Api.c 62

I use stackoverflow for the first time, I am sorry for my incompleteness!

Comment: `&xIID_ICMLuaUtil` remove the &.

Comment: c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\guiddef.h line 119

Comment: #define REFIID const IID * __MIDL_CONST

Comment: @RetiredNinja #define REFIID const IID * __MIDL_CONST IN c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\guiddef.h line 119

Comment: @BoPersson #define REFIID const IID * __MIDL_CONST IN c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\guiddef.h line 119

Comment: @BoPersson that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @Fen if you have additional information to add to your question then make an Edit to your question. Don't post a series of comments

Comment: Well, now it's a question with a poor example, and I'm not going to figure out the headers and such needed to compile it and see the error for myself.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm so sorry.I use stackoverflow for the first time.Sorry!!!

Comment: @M.M I' so so so sorry!!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `&` operator from `&xIID_ICMLuaUtil` in the call to `ucmMasqueradedCoGetObjectElevate`.

As shown by the error message, that parameter is a reference to `IID` (not a REFIID).